# Gulp-js task to minify non-minified files and concatenate with minified files

Tags: npm, concatenation, build-process, gulp, minify

How to write a gulp-js task which minifies only non-minified files and concatenated them with already minified files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Minify and transfer non-minified files to a temp folder
gulp.task('scripts1', function() {
  return gulp.src(['js/*.js', '!js/*.min.js'])
    .pipe(fixmyjs({}))
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js/new'))
    //.pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts1 task complete to minify' }));
});
//transfer minified files to the same temp folder
gulp.task('scripts2',['scripts1'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['js/*.min.js','js/rev-slider/*.min.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js/new'))
    //.pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts2 task complete to copy minified files' }));
});
//concat all minified files to a new dist folder
gulp.task('scripts3',['scripts2'], function() {
  return gulp.src('dist/assets/js/new/*.min.js')
    .pipe(order([
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/bootstrap.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.appear.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.countTo.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/waypoints.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.prettyPhoto.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/modernizr-latest.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/SmoothScroll.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.sticky.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/owl.carousel.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.isotope.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/jquery.mapmarker.min.js',
                'dist/assets/js/new/scripts.min.js'
            ], { base: './' }))
    .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts3 task complete to concat all minified files' }));
});
//delete the temp folder
gulp.task('cleantempjs',['scripts3'], function(cb) {
    del('dist/assets/js/new', cb)
});
//Now run the default task with clean task
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
   del(['dist/assets/css', 'dist/assets/js', 'dist/assets/img'], cb)
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
   gulp.start('cleantempjs');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[gulp-minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify) has a `ignoreFiles` option, so you can pass all files in a stream and have it discriminate in applying the minify.